# Why would you create your own custom exception class?

Tags: c++, exception

I am new to C++, and I would like to understand why would you create your own custom exception class.

I have been reading some books and online material where they specify that you can create your own exception class but they do not explain why and when would you want to create one.

Why would you create this class

```
class ArrayException
{
private:
    std::string mError;
public:
    ArrayException(std::string error) : mError(error) {}
    const char *GetError()
{
    return mError.c_str();
}
};
```

Inside our custom `IntegerArray` container class

```
    if(index < 0 || index >= GetLength())
        {
            throw ArrayException("Invalid index");
        }
```

Inside `main()`

```
    int main()
    {
        IntArray arr;
    try
    {
        arr[6] = 100;

    }
    catch(ArrayException error)
    {
        std::cout << "An exception has been caught! " << 
        error.GetError() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
```

And why not use

```
if(index < 0 || index >= GetLength())
    {
        throw "Invalid index";
```

Inside `main()`

```
int main()
{
IntArray arr;
try
{
    arr[6] = 100;

}
catch(const char *error)
{
    std::cout << "An exception has been caught! " << error << 
    std::endl;
}
return 0;

}
```

This is one of the example in the lessons.

Would it not be easy just to throw and catch an exception the normal way?
I hope my question makes sense as English is not my first language.

Comment: for the same reason you write your own (non excpetion) classes. Excpetions are not just strings with an error message. Just as a contrived example, the `ArrayException` could even store a copy of the array such that the catching code could inspect it

Comment: "*And why not use*" `if(index < 0 || index >= GetLength()) { throw "Invalid index";` - because it is a bad idea to throw strings like that.  They convey nothing to the catcher about the nature of the error that caused the `throw`. The standard library defines several custom exception classes, in this case `std::out_of_range`, eg: `if(index < 0 || index >= GetLength()) { throw std::out_of_range("Invalid index");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why would you create your own custom exception class?

Because the exception can be caught by class, and the custom class allows the catcher to perform a custom catch clause. Example:

```
while(true) {
    try {
        do_something();
    } catch(custom_recoverable_exception& e) {
        // assume that we know about this exception; why it is thrown
        // and how to fix the problem in case it is thrown
        recover(e.custom_data);
        continue; // try again
    } catch(std::exception& e) {
        // some other exception; we don't know how to recover
        diagnose_exception(e); // write to a log or to standard output
        throw; // re-rhrow: Maybe the caller of this function knows how to proceed
    }

    proceed_with_the_loop();
```

> Would it not be easy just to throw and catch an exception the normal way?

Throwing and catching an object of a custom class *is* the normal way.

If you mean, why not throw a pointer to string: Because if all thrown objects have the same type, then you cannot handle one throw differently from another.

---

Note that it is conventional to inherit custom exception classes from `std::exception` (or one of its subclasses) so that users of the function can handle your custom exceptions with same logic as standard exceptions in case they don't need special handling.